# String.format returns null in Spring Boot after retrieving information from application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, null

I have a Spring Boot application, using Intellij, and am trying to use the `@Value` annotation in order to get an environment variable from my `application.properties`.

My `application.properties` looks like this

```
server.port=27019
web.entrance.id=63d284ec
```

Using debugger, I can see that the value of `entranceId` is successfully retrieved from `application.properties`, but the same variable is always `null` in the `String.format` and my WebUrl has the string 'null' in it and I don't understand why.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

  @Value(("${entrance.id}"))
  private String entranceId;

  String WebUrl = String.format("http://localhost:27019/%s", entranceId);
```

Can someone explain if there is some detail I'm missing why this happens?
Thank you

Comment: Ofcourse it is null. The value is oly set AFTER the object has been constructed. The `WebUrl` is being set during object initialization/construction and at that point `entranceId` is still `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you elaborate a bit on that? My understanding is, `entranceId` is being assigned a value from the `application.properties`, and THEN the next line of code related to `WebUrl` is being executed. By then, my understanding is that `entranceId` has a value assigned to it. And then it should be replaced in the URL. Can you explain what is the gap in my chain of thinking?

Comment: Spring cannot inject a value in an object that hasn't been constructed. So there is nothing when the object is being created. That is also the time you are reading the value and not after construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is wrong. Spring will process the `@Value` **after** the object has been constructed, whereas your field is being initialized as soon as the class is being constructed (so during constructing).

Basically what Spring does

1. `new Controller()`
2. Detect `@Value` and with reflection set value
3. Any construction callbacks (like `@PostConstruct`).

Your field is being filled at step 1 **not** after step 2. At which point the `@Value` hasn't yet been processed.

If you want to set the value you need to do that in an `@PostConstruct` method **or** use constructor injection to construct the URL.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for taking the time to write a detailed response!